# assembly crap games. My code can't complete exit and stuck in a loop

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Write a program that plays the game of Craps using the rules stated above so that it simulates a game without human input.   Instead of asking for a wager, the program should just calculate if the player would win or lose.  Create a function that simulates rolling the two dice and returns the sum.  Add a loop so that the program plays 10,000 games.  Add counters that count how many times the player wins, and how many times the player loses.  At the end of the 10,000 games, List total Wins and Losses for output.   Over the long run, who is going to win the most games of Craps, you or the house?

this is my code.
I think it stuck on an endless loop.
Please point out what I need to fix.

```
include Irvine32.inc

.data
point dword ?
winCount dword 0
loseCount dword 0
dice1 dword ?     ; 1 to 6
dice2 dword ?     ; 1 to 6
.code
 main PROC
    call clrscr
    mov ecx, 10
    call play

    mov eax, winCount
    call writedec
    call crlf
    mov eax, loseCount
    call writedec
    main endp

random1 PROC    ;generate first number
    mov eax, 5
    call randomrange
    inc eax
    mov dice1, eax    
    ret
    random1 endp

random2 PROC    ;generate second number
    mov eax, 5
    call randomrange
    inc eax
    mov dice2, eax 
    ret
    random2 endp

reroll PROC

    call random1
    call random2
    mov eax, dice1
    mov ebx, dice2
    add eax, ebx
    cmp eax,7
    je win
    cmp eax, point
    je lose
    jmp reroll
    ret
    reroll endp


win PROC
    mov eax, winCount
    inc eax
    mov winCount, eax
    jmp play
    ret
    win endp

lose PROC
    mov eax, loseCount
    inc eax
    mov loseCount, eax
    jmp play
    ret
    lose endp

play PROC


    playloop:
    call random1
    call random2
    mov eax, dice1
    mov ebx, dice2
    add eax, ebx
    mov point, eax
    cmp eax, 7
    je win 
    cmp eax, 11
    je win 

    cmp eax, 2
    je lose
    cmp eax, 3
    je lose
    cmp eax, 12
    je lose

    cmp eax, 4
    je reroll
    cmp eax, 5
    je reroll
    cmp eax, 6
    je reroll
    cmp eax, 8
    je reroll
    cmp eax, 9
    je reroll
    cmp eax, 10
    je reroll

    loop playloop

    ret
    play endp

    end main
```

Comment: Use the debugger to single step and find out which loop your code gets stuck in, and look at register values.

Comment: Some of your functions `jmp` somewhere else, making their `ret` unreachable.  `reroll` even jumps to itself.  IDK if you're just abusing `proc` for blocks of code that aren't really functions or if your design is just fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it stuck on an endless loop.

The `loop playloop` instruction can never be reached!
When throwing 2 dice, the outcome is a number in the range [2,12].
Your code has cases for every possible value:

- 7 and 11 go to *win*
- 2, 3, and 12 go to *lose*
- 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, and 10 go to *reroll*

There's no way to fall through in the `loop`instruction that would otherwise limit the playing time. There's your endless loop.

> Please point out what I need to fix.

I don't know this *game of Craps* and so it's impossible to even start suggesting decisive corrections.
What I can tell you is that *win*, *lose*, and *reroll* ought to be labels **within the *play* proc**, and not procs by themselves.

IDEA

Your text says:

> ...the game of Craps using the rules stated above...

It's probably best to actually include these rules with your post.

Comment: I was able to fix my endless loop.